What's this plastic strip called that functions like multiple wires?

What's this this plastic strip called that functions like multiple wires?
Am I likely to be able to order  placement for this one? And does it usually come with connectors on each end?
The device, earbuds case, has been wet and I noticed it's especially affected the connector at the top of the plastic strip.
I'm hoping to be able to replace the strip including connectors.
However, when I pulled the plastic strip, it just started sliding out from the connector instead of taking the plug (if that's what black part is) with it.

That is a standard flat flex cable.
The cable comes terminated (the blue rigid plastic strip on the end) so it can be inserted into connectors.
And no it does not come with connectors, if you mean those soldered to PCB. If they are broken, damaged or corroded, you need to find them and replace separately. There are different kinds of such connectors.
That black part on the connector is a lever that should hold the flat flex cable in place with enough force. It should be lifted up before pulling the cable out - but be extremely careful as it will easily break.

It is called flexible flat cable. Make sure you get a replacement with the correct arrangement of exposed conductors since that can't be easily changed.

I call that a ribbon cable first seen it in the nintendo gamecube and other consoles seems pretty fragile from what i remember

It is similar to a ribbon cable, admittedly, but a ribbon cable is (generally) more robust and flexible. From the photo, the delicate traces aren't all that flexible (as you as "pretty fragile") and are much flatter (than the cables in a ribbon cable) - hence it is a "flat flex cable". See Flat Wire vs Ribbon Wire: What Sets Them Apart?

Looks like your right to me Flat flex cable there 5-15 bucks thanks for teaching me somethin new!

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

@Rob "Looks like [*you're] right " Then please delete your answer, as it's wrong.

@DavideAndrea - Hi, Just FYI this is an answer (i.e. it's not a question, or something irrelevant - it is definitely an answer to the OP's specific question), so the feedback you chose that "this does not provide an answer ..." was an incorrect choice. || It's a wrong answer, agreed, but wrong answers still count as answers on Stack Exchange. The point is that voting will push wrong answers to the bottom of the list :) Sometimes even wrong answers serve a useful purpose, by comments (like the 1st one below this answer) explaining why it's wrong, for future readers. TY
